# How to add an object to a NSMutable array that is in a class?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am trying to add an object of the same class to a NSMutable array that is defined in the same class.
My approach would look like this, but when I tested the array, it was always empty. I also tried adding random Strings or integers.

**The .h file:**

```
@property NSMutableArray *anArray;
- (void)addObject: (TheClass*)nameOfObjectToBeAdded;
```

**The .m file:**

```
@synthesize anArray;

- (void)addObject: (TheClass*)nameOfObjectToBeAdded {
    [anArray addObject:nameOfObjectToBeAdded];
}
```

**The main.m:**

```
#import "TheClass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        TheClass *object1 = [[TheClass alloc] init];
        TheClass *object2 = [[TheClass alloc] init];
        [object1 addObject:object2];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to add object2 to the NSMutableArray of object1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allocate and initialize the array before using it:

In Class.m, probably in `init`:

```
self.anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Great, if it worked for you feel free to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create NSMutableArray at first..

```
NSMutableArray *anArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[anArray addObject:object];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the allocation in your classes initializer as such:

In `ThisClass`

```
-(id) init: {
  self = [super init];
  if(self) {
    self.anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    /* ... other initializer stuff ... */
  }
  return self;
}
```